# Validation plugin for mongoose

Tags: validation, mongoose

Is there a good validation plugin for mongoose. I found this https://npmjs.org/package/mongoose-validator but it did not find good documentation for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mongoose validator is not particularly useful, it's just syntactic sugar for your schema that points to [node-validator](https://github.com/chriso/node-validator).
For your validation I would recommend using [node-validator](https://github.com/chriso/node-validator) directly and wrapping it in a function supplied to your field's "validate" option.

For example, let's say we wanted a URL plugin that adds and validates a URL field in your schema:

```
  validator= require 'validator'

  UrlPlugin = ( schema, options = {} ) ->
    field = options.field || 'url'

    fields = {}
    fields[field] =
      type: String
      validate: [
        ( value ) ->
          try
            return true if validator.check(value).isUrl()
          catch err
            return false
        "URL Error"
      ]

    schema.add fields
```